# Having a problem about printing out object on console

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I try to create a car object with the given values. While function is working, I print them on console and everything seems OK, however, when ı look the properties of car2 no values assigns it.My code is the following.

```
            function Car()
        {
            this.brand = "";
            this.wheel = 0;
            this.crash = false;
        }

  Car.prototype.createNewCar2 = function(array)
        {
            for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    Object.keys(this)[i] = array[i];  
                    console.log(Object.keys(this)[i]);
                    console.log(array[i]);
                }
        }

        var car2 = new Car();
        car2.createNewCar2(["bmw",12,true]);
        console.log(car2);
```

When I create newcar I assign the values to the right index. I see it when I console.log them. However after creation, no values assigned to the car object. I couldn't figure out what is the problem. thanks in advance. My output is the following

```
brand
bmw
wheel
12
crash
true
Car {brand: "", wheel: 0, crash: false}
```

Comment: What is this suppose to do: `Object.keys(this)[i] = array[i]`? You have to do `this[propertyName] = value`

Comment: Taking the properties of Car object and assign them elements in the array

Comment: @SüleymanAcar Don't do that, `Object.keys` does not guarantee property order. Instead explicitly write out `[this.brand, this.wheel, this.crash] = array;`. Or even better, don't take an array as an argument but use multiple parameters?

Comment: You are right but I was just trying to get new methods to do that but thanks for recommodation. @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not assigning the value to the object's property using `this`. You are simply overwriting the `key` of the object. You need to assign the value of the object using `this`:

```
var keys = Object.keys(this);
this[keys[i]] = array[i];
```

```js
function Car() {
  this.brand = "";
  this.wheel = 0;
  this.crash = false;
}

Car.prototype.createNewCar2 = function(array) {
  var keys = Object.keys(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    this[keys[i]] = array[i];
    console.log(Object.keys(this)[i]);
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
}

var car2 = new Car();
car2.createNewCar2(["bmw", 12, true]);
console.log(car2);
```

Comment: Cyristal clear sir. Thank you for explanation. @Angit Agarwal

Comment: @SüleymanAcar Though this is one way to do it, ideally, it should be done in constructor

Comment: @Rajesh agree with you. Answer was given based on code context of the OP

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yup. I understood that. Hence added a comment as a caveat. Though this can be improved, question in my understanding fell under typographical area and hence did not answer.